# ASP.NET WebFormsMVP PageDataSource Events Executing Twice For Unknown Reason

Tags: asp.net, webforms, webformsmvp

The problem is *SelectMethod* and other actions execute twice. This has been difficult to isolate, as it only occurs on a larger solution, and not in simpler demo applications.

```
//.ascx
<asp:FormView runat="server" DataSourceID="userSource" DefaultMode="Edit">
    <EditItemTemplate>

<mvp:PageDataSource id="userSource" SelectMethod="GetUser" />

//code behind 
public User GetUser()
{
     //returning single item as FormView is only DefaultMode=edit
     return Model.User;
}

//presenter
public class UserOtherEditPresenter<IUserOtherEditView<UserEditViewModel>>
```

In an attempt to debug this here is the trace [AXD file](http://github.com/NickJosevski/WebFormsMVP-ProductEdit-Sample/blob/master/misc_trace/useredit.axd).

**Update:**

As it has been pointed out that initialization seems fine, so the problem must lie elsewhere in a conflict with some other aspect of the application.

Comment: AXD file is the trace.axd for the page where this occurs, and the GitHub repo is a demo app that does not experience the same issue but is setup in a similar way.

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be with the registration or initialization at all (you can see in the Trace.axd that the user control was found and registered once). I'd really need a sample of a page that actually exhibits this issue to help debug it.

Comment: is ViewState enabled for this page? If so not,there are senerios in which the select method will be called twice [I have seen this with ObjectDatasource]

Comment: As Brian picks up on, there are some scenarios where the ObjectDataSource will call the select method twice. The MVP Page Data Source is just a thin wrapper around the ObjectDataSource that turns the method calls into events so that a presenter can subscribe to them.

I'd continue your research into this issue by investigating the ObjectDataSource.

Comment: @brian chandley thanks for the suggestion Brian, I ensured ViewState is disabled, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: @Tatham Oddie thanks, it seems issues with ObjectDataSource are popular on StackOverflow, will continue investigating that direction.

Comment: @Nick Josevski enable view state. see if this double execution happens. I saw this behavior when EnableViewstate=false. There is key data in viewstate that that is no longer availiable when EnableViewstate=false. to get that data, The ODS/Grid needs to know. In this case: wne going to page 2 from page 1,  it may be hitting the select or page one first, then again for page 2. Normally page1 data in availiable from Viewstate.

Comment: @brian chandley, oh sorry I misunderstood your comment, the state of viewstate either enabled or disabled on the page and controls doesn't prevent this behaviour from occurring.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post this as a comment on your question but SO either isn't giving me that privilege because I have an insufficient number of badges (can I trade in FourSquare ones?), or the UX is just confusing me too much. Here's my non-answer answer:

Is the trace.axd you sent meant to demonstrate the problem? It all looks normal to me. It's only binding one presenter:

> Creating presenter of type ADC.Logic.Presenters.UserOtherEditPresenter for view of type ADC.Logic.Views.IUserOtherEditView`1[[ADC.Logic.Views.Models.UserEditViewModel, ADC.Logic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]. (The actual view instance is of type ASP.controls_userotheredit_ascx.

According to the *title* of your question we'd expect to see this event twice.

However, the *title* and the *content* of your question don't match for me. You're saying the SelectMethod gets fired multiple times, which could indicate a problem with the PageDataSource.

Can you clarify please?

Comment: Yes the page title I chose doesn't reflect what the actual problem is, it is in fact only the PageDataSource methods that are executing twice. I will amend the question title.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the quick fix is to set AutoDataBind = false for your user control.  This stops the second call to DataBind of the FormView which in turn stops the second call to the SelectMethod.
The first call to formView.DataBind happens as part of Page.ProcessRequestMain and happens due to the DataSourceID on the datagrid.